# Create tag with multiple values in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, tags

**Hello**,

I'm creating a lambda function on AWS to automatically create tags on EC2 resources.
The solution works fine:

> ```
> ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids,Tags=[{'Key':'environnement','Value':'dev'}])
> ```

My question:

Can i create a tag with limited values? like a drop down list ?

So users can only choose from this list ?

> ```
> ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids,Tags=[{'Key':'environnement','Value':['dev','prod','test']}])
> ```

**Thanks in advance !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an IAM policy to the cloudwatch service to create tags only if the expected key/value pair matches. Sample IAM policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Env": [
                        "Prod",
                        "Stage",
                        "Dev"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This will only allow if Env tag is being created with values Prod/Stage/Dev. You can add any number of key/value pair to the policy based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Cloudformation, you may pre-define set of values to be selected by the user.
2. You may also enforce tags and values using IAM Role permissions, but this will only validate the request, not prompt the user to select any tags/values.
   Refer: [Tag based permissions](https://pubudu.dev/posts/aws-iam-tag-based-permissions/)